# XSLT namespace versions

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am using XSLT 1.0. Is there a way to deal with input document namespace versions ?

For instance, I used to have input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc:TheTag xmlns:abc="http://example.com/xmls/2014">
    <abc:hello>world</abc:hello>
</abc:TheTag>
```

with XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:abc="http://example.com/xmls/2014">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="abc:TheTag/abc:hello"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now the input changed to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc:TheTag xmlns:abc="http://example.com/xmls/2016">
    <abc:hello>world</abc:hello>
</abc:TheTag>
```

i.e. 2014 to 2016

I have to deal with both versions of the input XML though and the parts my style sheet addresses are common to both 2014 and 2016 i.e. the style sheet it self needs no change.

So, is there a way to use one style sheet to work with both versions of the input ?

BTW: XSLT 2.0 makes it simpler by introducing *:TheTag/*:hello but migrating to version 2.0 is a last option for me as it means moving to a new XSLT processor altogether

Comment: Apologies, I meant schema versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it really generic (complicated) and are sure that no clashes occur, you could also use

```
 <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'TheTag']/*[local-name() = 'hello']"/>
```

or

```
  <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'TheTag' and starts-with(namespace-uri(),
 'http://example.com/xmls/2')]/*[local-name() = 'hello' and 
  starts-with(namespace-uri(),'http://example.com/xmls/2')]"/>
```

(untested code)

Edit - there was a slash missing in the first code line

Comment: Err, I'd say yes is should, what problem does occur?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns14="http://example.com/xmls/2014"
xmlns:ns16="http://example.com/xmls/2016">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns14:TheTag/ns14:hello | ns16:TheTag/ns16:hello"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That is also the only solution I could come up with thus far. I just hoped there is something simpler as the practical impact is orders of magnitude more complicated than my contrived example unfortunately. It seems a two-pass approach to simply rename all namespaces with schema version changes as step 1 would be simplest.